# code/text manipulation with pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I do not know the exact word for the manipulation I am looking for, so I will try to explain it with an example.

A couple of days ago I saw a programming podcast, where a person was doing text manipulation in IDE (I will give you an example of what he did, because I do not remember the youtube link). For example starting with text

```
one 1
two 2
three 3
four 4
five 5
six 6
seven 7
eight 8 
nine 9
```

he transformed it to

```
"One", 1
"Two", 2
"Three", 3
"Four", 4
"Five", 5
"Six", 6
"Seven", 7
"Eight", 8
"Nine", 9
```

with just a 2-4 key combinations (select text, add left ", right " and ,). I felt really bad because I was always spending significant amount of time formatting such text or if the text is big, writing a program to do this.

The question is: how to do this with pycharm

Answer (score 1):

(Windows key bindings)

1. Make single selection with one caret per line with `MMB+drag` or `alt+shift+insert` on selected text.
2. Move to line start with `home`.
3. Type `"`.
4. Select first characters with `shift+right`
5. Toggle case with `ctrl+shift+u`
6. Move to word end with `ctrl+right`
7. Type `", "`

Read [Multiple Selections in PyCharm](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2014/09/feature-spotlight-multiple-selections-in-pycharm/) blog post for more info.